# Youtube Button Height

Tags: css, button, youtube, height, developer-tools

I have been trying to adjust the height of the YouTube button to match the height of other social media button on the page, but I cannot seem to get any call out to work. Seems like this should be relatively easy.

This is the site: http://www.sunsetstudiosent.com in the social section of the index page.

And here is the code I am currently running:

```css
.nav--social__link.yt-button{
  height: 40px !important;
  overflow: visible;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 79px;
  margin-right: 4px;
}
.g-ytsubscribe{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle !important;
  font-size: 1px;
  line-height: normal; font-size: 1px;
  text-indent: 0px; 
  padding: 0px; 
  background: transparent none repeat scroll 0% 0%; 
  border-style: none; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just specified the height of `<li>` but the height of the children element remains the same, and so do the style in the iframe.

You can achieve this, though it's quite complicated. You need to add the following css to your code.

```
li.nav--social__link.yt-button * {
    height: 40px !important;
}
```

Then, use js to insert another line of code into the iframe.

```
.yt-uix-button.yt-uix-button-subscribe-branded {
    height: 28px !important;
}
```

Comment: Writing js is a bit beyond my capabilities. I can cut and paste into the page, but that is about it. It should be mentioned that the only code I entered on the site is the code as given by YouTube. The iframe is all being generated through google scripts I believe and is not manually added to the site. There is not strictly CSS fix for this?

Comment: I'm afraid not. The CSS on your page can NOT style the elements in `iframe` and if you inspect that element, you can see a css file from Youtube set the height to 24px. But I'm not familiar with youtube api. There should be a way to edit it from there side, I think. @ThisGuy